# Python: How to loop through hierarchical columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, hierarchy

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(index = ['2018-01-01','2018-01-02','2018-01-03','2018-01-04'])
df["ticker"] = ['TSLA', 'TSLA', 'IBM', 'IBM']
df["price"] = ['1000', '1200', '101', '108']
df["volume"] = ['100000', '123042', '1087878', '108732']
df["marketcap"] = ['1.2T', '1.4T', '30B', '35B']
df.index.rename('Date', inplace=True)
df.set_index('ticker', append=True).unstack('ticker').swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1,level=0, sort_remaining=False)
df:
                 TSLA                              IBM         
                 price  volume  marketcap          price  volume    marketcap
          Date              
    2018-01-01   1000   100000  1.2T               NaN    NaN       NaN
    2018-01-02   1200   123042  1.4T               NaN    NaN       NaN
    2018-01-03   NaN    NaN     NaN                101    1087878   30B
    2018-01-04   NaN    NaN     NaN                108    108732    35B
```

How can loop through the ticker (i.e. TSLA) and from that take only the price column for each date?
So something like this:

```
  for col in df.columns(level=0):
      for i in df.index:
          if df.columns(level=1)=="price":
              df_price=df[col].loc[i]
```

And df_price looks something like this:

```
              TSLA
      Date 
2018-01-01    1000
```

and so on for the rest of the prices and tickers.
Thank you.

Comment: if you want all columns price, then this `df.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:, 'price']]` should do it, is it what you are after?

Comment: `df.loc(axis=1)[:, 'price']` or `df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(['price'], level=1)]` are other options.

Comment: `df.loc(axis=1)[('TSLA', 'price')]`

Comment: Thank you all! @Ben.T and Henry, both your solutions worked

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Date"], columns=["ticker"], values=["price"])


            price
ticker      IBM     TSLA
Date        
2018-01-01  NaN     1000.0
2018-01-02  NaN     1200.0
2018-01-03  101.0   NaN
2018-01-04  108.0   NaN
```